# Getting Unicoins after disabling the sidebar?

Tags: support, unicoins

So, I disabled my sidebar widget using 20 of my Unicoins and now I can't seem to get access to the widget for recycling it. I simply see something like this:

[image: img]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access it from the footer.

[image]

Comment: i'm confused, i can't find the circle??//

Comment: People browse all the way to the bottom? o_0

Comment: @hjpotter92 To be fair, the unicorn power that removes the unicoins from the sidebar _does_ tell you it'll still appear at the bottom.